# Is there a way to delete a shape with an extrusion

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to delete a part of a shape with an extrusion.
The shape:

[image]

[image]

This is to make a fluid simulation where blocks of water will flow in each of the top three holes and out through the bottom three holes.

Comment: Welcome to Blender Stackexchange. Please learn [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post) about how to embed images into your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Use the inset tool (Keyboard shortcut: <kbd>I</kbd>)

Select the faces, inset, and use the inset individual option.

from there you can extrude.

[image]

To make a though cut, select faces on top and bottom, inset, delete the newly created faces, select the edges on top and bottom and use bridge edge loops to connect top and bottom. (bridge edge loops

[image]

Comment: Incidentally.. in this particular case, you don't need to delete the faces to make the bridge, and the 'Loop Pairs' setting in Bridge Edge Loops will do them all at once. Not really relevant unless you're doing hundreds at a time .. :)